# Hiding Push Notification if message sent by user

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions

In my app user can post content and everyone who follow a specific group gets a notification about that sent post.

Right now also the sender receives a notification that he sent a message which should not happen.

In the background I manage this with firebase function.
In the frontend I want to check if the user ID of the device is the same user ID from the person who sent the message. If so the notification should not be displayed.

I did this with a simple if else statement but still the sender gets a notification.
What is wrong here?

```
var receivedUserID: String?
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let pushPlaceID = userInfo["placeID"] as? String {
            ViewController.placeidUebertragen = pushPlaceID
        }

        if let pushCommentID = userInfo["commentID"] as? String {
            ViewComments.subComment = pushCommentID
            ViewComments.commentIDNew = pushCommentID
        }

        if let pushUserID = userInfo["newUserID"] as? String {
            receivedUserID = pushUserID
        }

        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        if let pushUserID = receivedUserID,
           pushUserID != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
            completionHandler([])
        } else {            
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
    }
```